# How to find a specific value from a pandas Data Frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to know how will I find a specific value from a Dataframe. I have a value **?** spread across my data frame and its time consuming to check every column in a data frame. Is there any easy way to get the columns name that contains that specific value? For example, I have **?** spread across my **car** database.

I can do this easily via column as below:

```
df_car['bhp'].where(df_car['bhp']=?) //something like this
```

Can I get an easy way to fetch all **?** and **0** value and then replace it?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use df.replace to replace all `?`

Comment: question is in other context Vaishali

Comment: I am not quite sure what do you mean. Doesn't your question say, "Can I get an easy way to fetch all ? and 0 value and then replace it?"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to find all columns with `?` or `0` in them?

Then you can use `df.isin()`, it's find some value whether in `df`

This example will show how to find df's column where them include value `"italy"`  and `1`.

```py
>>> import pandsa as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['canada', 'canada', 'italy', 'italy'], 'item': ['coke', 'coke', 'pepsi', 'coke'], 'weight': [1, 1, 2, 1]})
  location   item  weight
0   canada   coke       1
1   canada   coke       1
2    italy  pepsi       2
3    italy   coke       1

>>> res = df[df.isin([1, "italy"])].notna().any()
>>> columns = res[res].index.tolist()
>>> print(columns)
['location', 'weight']
```

Output is `['location', 'weight']` because `"italy"` in column `location`, and `1` in column `weight`